# preg_replace escaping <? and ?>

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove the *first* occurrence of `<?` and the *last* occurrence of `?>` from a string using preg_replace, but no matter how I attempt to escape them, they always cause trouble.

**PHP Code**

```
$string = preg_replace('/<?/', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/?>/', '', $string);
```

What shall I write into the expression area?

Comment: `$string = preg_replace('/\<\?/', '', $string);` and `$string = preg_replace('/\?\>/', '', $string);`. Use `\ ` to take characters as literals.

Comment: @AndreiP.: Why are you escaping `>`  and `<`? They haven't special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^((?:(?!<\?).)*)<\?|\?>(?!.*?\?>)/s', '$1', $string);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lL9vI3/1)

Or quite simply:

```
$string = preg_replace('/<\?(.*)\?>/s', '$1', $string);
```

**PS:** Note that you can do this without using regex also. Use `strpos` and `strrpos` functions in PHP to get first position of `<?` and last position of `?>` and then use `substr` function.

Comment: Actually this one isn't right. I tested it with 'Testing <? some <? text ?> here ?> too' and it removes "Testing" as well.

Comment: Or to make it simple: `$string = preg_replace('/<\?(.*)\?>/s', '$1', $string);`

Comment: That's pretty funny: I can see that it works in your working exaxmple, but I've tested it twice now in PHP and there it does remove "Testing". The first regex you posted that is, not the second.

Comment: Actually it is working, you didn't use `$1` in replacement. **[See this modified working demo](http://ideone.com/hqw33f)**

Comment: Like you don't in your example. So like I've set many times now: your first example isn't correct.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed out that myself. Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$str = preg_replace('~<\?(.*)\?>~s', '$1', $str);
```

But if you are running an old php version that may interpret `?>` as an end tag. you can use this trick:

```
$str = preg_replace('~<\?(.*)\?'.'>~s', '$1', $str);
```